# What is general workflow with client side Typescript app and GraphQL backend

Tags: typescript, graphql, application-design

I have a client side React Typescript application. And I read that it's good practice to create Interfaces for responses coming from endpoints.

For example GraphQL schema declared this type:

```
type Author {
  id: Int!
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
  ... {more fields}
  posts(findTitle: String): [Post]
}
```

So on client side I also need to create similar interface:

```
interface Post: {...}

interface IAuthor {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  posts: Post[]
}
```

And when client application receive response, it just will cast response to this interface, like this:

```
const data = await getWholeAuthorFromGraphQL();
const user = data as IUser;
```

But one thing not clear to me is that GraphQL allows to fetch specific fields instead of whole object.

For example in some other place of application I also need `IUser` object, but only with 2 fields: `firstName` and `secondName`. Should I create another interface in this case?  Like:

```
interface AuthorFullname {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

Or can I just cast to `IUser` anything that belongs to `Author` GQL type? And then in code I will be careful because I will know that `user` object contains only `firstName` and `lastName`. So I will not use other fields than `firstName` and `lastName`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with having generated code, on your client application you can use a tool called [apollo codegen](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling#apollo-clientcodegen-output).

Basically it checks for every place where you defined your queries `gql` and together with the server `schema` definition it generates the necessary `Interfaces` for the defined queries. So, if you define nested queries or queries with fragments it will just generate the interfaces you need to execute them.

Here is also a good article about [Generate TypeScript Definitions for GraphQL Queries](https://medium.com/open-graphql/automatically-generate-typescript-definitions-for-graphql-queries-with-apollo-codegen-e73eae72b561).

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question, given the GraphQL interface can potentially return partial versions of the interface, you're better off using Typescript HOC types like Partial

```
const getResult : Partial<MyModel> = await yourNetworkRequest()
```

Partial in this instance will make each attribute optional, which means you can do existence checking at the actual call site for the response. This is particularly useful if you have Typescript set to strict mode.

Alternately you could have your call

```
function myNetworkCall() : Partial<MyModel>
```

Which again applies the same thing, you then have to do the heavy lifting to make sure the fields you're looking for exist (by existence checking)

```
// assume the following
interface MyModel {
 field1: string;
 field2: string;
}




const item = myNetworkCall()
if(item.field1){
 // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to simply create interfaces specific to each query you actually use in your code. For example, given two queries:

```
query QueryA {
  allAuthors {
    id
    firstName
    lastName
    posts {
      ...PostFields
    }
  }
}

query QueryB {
  id
  firstName
  lastName
}
```

We can just make two separate interfaces, one for each query:

```
interface QueryAAuthor {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  posts: QueryAPost[];
}

interface QueryBAuthor {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

While this does create more interfaces and generates additional complexity in your code, it also means there's no ambiguity when you're working with the result of a query. For example, if we were to use a single interface with `Partial` instead, I could still reference `posts` even when dealing with QueryB's result and the compiler would not catch it.

This is actually the approach used by [Apollo CLI](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling)'s codegen feature, which lets you generate types based on a schema and your client-side queries.

I don't think this is the only way to handle it -- it's just a question of how much type safety you want in your code.